# command pipe into subshell

Tags: unix, tee

What is the difference between

```
cat dat | tee >(wc -l ) | some other command
```

and

```
cat dat | tee file | wc -l
```

in terms of what is happening under the hood?
I can understand the second one as tee is forking the stream into a file and also to a pipe. But I am confused with the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first notation is the [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) of Bash 4.x (not in 3.x, or not all versions of 3.x).

As far as `tee` is concerned, it is given a file name (such as `/dev/fd/64`) to which it writes as well as to standard output; it is actually a file descriptor for the write end of a pipe.  As far as `wc` is concerned, it reads its standard input (which is the read end of the pipe that is connected to `/dev/fd/64` for `tee`), and writes its answer to the standard output of the shell invoking the pipeline (not the standard output of `tee` which goes down the pipeline).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I may ask yet another question, how is process substitution different from the one with the dollar sign in front of parens such as $(command)(which I don't know the name for it)? for example, var=$(basename file) works correctly, but var=(basename file) doesn't. Why is it so?

Comment: The `$(command)` substitution is called ['command substitution'](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution). The difference is that in general, each command substitution expands to multiple arguments to the program, whereas each [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) results in a single argument to the program. Using a feeble example: `ls $(echo *.*)` generates many file name arguments, whereas `ls <(echo *.*)` would give `ls` a single argument (when I tried `ls <(echo *.*)` it responded `/dev/fd/63`!).

Comment: I found this reference really helpful for understanding process substitution: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Answer (score 1):

Since >( is process substitiution of bash,
the first line says:
send the contents of file 'dat' into some other command
while process 'wc' is run with its input or output
connected to a pipe which also sends the content of 'dat'

check "Process Substitution" of bash manpage.